# Its possible to change the "webstorm" shell command to open a file in WebStorm?

Tags: macos, terminal, command, webstorm

I open files in WebStorm from the terminal with the command `webstorm .` when I'm working in a directory.

Is there a way to change the command `webstorm` to anything more, like `wstorm` or something shorter to open files fluently?

I'm using macOS.

Comment: A hint: In linux systems you edit your .bashrc that is located in your home folder and create a alias: alias wstorm='webstorm'. I'm not using mac but you can find a similar way with this tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Know one way but it's temporary, works untill you close the terminal.

**-in your terminal**

> W=webstorm

then you can use $W in your command instead of webstorm.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the hint above is very good.
So assuming the shell script "webstorm" is working and your question is how to modify the command AND you want to do it fluently.

Make an alias (your shell may vary, mine is bash)
in the appropriate 'dot' file for your shell
add an alias for webstorm -e like this

```
alias we='webstorm -e'
```

now when I want to open a file quickly I type

```
we filename
```

And this opens Webstorm in LightEdit mode which opens faster and has a link to access full IDE.

Works like a charm. Also, you could make more than one alias so say ws for the full ide. Enjoy